# tensorflow input pipeline: how to transform data and sample?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to ditch my own implementation of a dataset, which is certainly slower than it could be and upgrade to `tensorflow.data.Dataset`.

There are however certain transformations that I need to apply to my data before it's fed to the network and I would like to understand how to do this with `Dataset`.

My data originates from a 3D tensor `P` of shape (X,Y,Z) (e.g. X=10, Y=10000, Z=3). I need to:

- take from `P` a (3D) [sliding window](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sliding_window_batch) of length N that makes M consecutive steps along Y,
- normalize each of the M chunks of data to the last value,
- return *geometrically distributed* random batches of such sliding windows

Can this be done with `Dataset`?

Comment: Generally, if it can be done on a single tensor, it can be done on a dataset using the `apply` function. Is the number of samples taken in the 3rd step fixed?

Comment: Yes it’s fixed, all of the dimensions are fixed from the start.